# Auto populate edit form laravel 5.4 without html collective

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Html Collective isn't out yet for laravel 5.4. Is there a way to auto populate edit forms ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, but you should be fine using Html Collective 5.3 with Laravel 5.4. I'm using those versions on a small project and haven't experienced any issues.